# Python- Using a function on a custom object(like numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, object, iteration

I created my own class for matrices, and I wondered how could I use a matrix as a parameter to a function that isn't supposed to recieve a matrix?
for example, you can use exp() on a numpy array. How could I copy that behaviour? I understood that it's something to do with **iter** and **next**(might be wrong, though)
My class-

```
import random
from numbers import Number
class matrix:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data= data
        self.rows= len(self.data)
        self.cols= len(self.data[0])
    def __str__(self):
        output="["
        for row in self.data:
            output+=str(row)
            if not row==self.data[-1]: output+=",\n"
        output+="]"
        return output

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Number):
            other = matrix([[other for i in range(self.cols)] for i in range(self.rows)])
        if not isinstance(other, matrix):
            raise Exception("Improper type to add")
        if not self.rows == other.rows or not self.cols == other.cols:
            raise Exception("Shapes do not match")
        new_data=self.data.copy()
        for i in range(len(new_data)):
            for j in range(len(new_data[0])):
                new_data[i][j]+=other.data[i][j]
        return matrix(new_data)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other*(-1))

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Number):
            data_copy= self.data.copy()
            for row in data_copy:
                for element in row:
                    element*=other
            return matrix(data_copy)
        if not isinstance(other, matrix):
            raise Exception("Improper type to multiply")
        if not self.cols== other.rows:
            raise Exception("Cant multiply object of dimensions %d with object of dimensions %d" % self.shape() % other.shape())

        new_data=[]
        for i in range(self.rows):
            new_data_row=[]
            for j in range(other.cols):
                temp_val=0
                for h in range(self.cols):
                    temp_val+=self.data[i][h] * other.data[h][j]
                new_data_row.append(temp_val)
            new_data.append(new_data_row)
        return matrix(new_data)

    def shape(self):
        return (self.rows, self.cols)

    def random(rows, cols, val):
        data = [[round(2*random.random()*val - val, 10) for i in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
        output= matrix(data)
        return output
```

Comment: Can you post any code you've written?

Comment: @John Yes of course, added the class.

Comment: If you pass your object to a numpy function, most likely it will try make an array from it.  It will use the array and return an array result.  If your `data` is a list of lists, `np.array(obj.data)` might work.